# iOS : Access JPEG metadata at Marker APP3

Tags: iphone, objective-c, metadata, exif

I have been using the Exif tags to store some data on jpeg files in the following manner:

```
CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(baseURL, NULL);
NSDictionary *metadata = (NSDictionary *) CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source,0,NULL);
NSMutableDictionary *metadataAsMutable = [[metadata mutableCopy]autorelease];
NSMutableDictionary *EXIFDictionary = [[[metadataAsMutable objectForKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary]mutableCopy]autorelease];
[EXIFDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",tag] forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyExifUserComment];
```

Now, I would like to use a custom Application Marker (APP3 at 0xFFE3) instead of Exif Marker.

(Refer - http://www.ozhiker.com/electronics/pjmt/jpeg_info/app_segments.html)

Could someone point me in the right direction.

PS: I am using a jailbroken iPad for this app.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it seems we have to go via file handler way for this. Here is what I did, though there may be a better way to do this.

Create a File handle:

```
NSString *filePath = currentImageObject.myFilePath;
NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:filePath];
if(!fileHandle){
   return; 
}
[fileHandle seekToEndOfFile];
unsigned long long eofOffset = [fileHandle offsetInFile];
```

Then iterate the file contents till you find a desired tag:

```
BOOL markerFound = NO;
BOOL dqtFound = NO;
while ((!markerFound) && (!dqtFound) && ([fileHandle offsetInFile] < eofOffset)) {
        currentOffset += 1;
        [fileHandle seekToFileOffset:currentOffset];
        NSData *markerData = [fileHandle readDataOfLength:1];
        currentOffset += 1;
        NSInteger markerValue = (unsigned char)*(unsigned char *)[markerData bytes];

        if (0xe0 == markerValue) {
            currentOffset += 14;
            [fileHandle seekToFileOffset:currentOffset];

            NSData *xThumbnailData = [fileHandle readDataOfLength:1];
            currentOffset += 1;
            NSData *yThumbnailData = [fileHandle readDataOfLength:1];
            currentOffset += 1;
            NSInteger xThumbnail = (unsigned char)*(unsigned char *)[xThumbnailData bytes];
            NSInteger yThumbnail = (unsigned char)*(unsigned char *)[yThumbnailData bytes];
            NSInteger thumbnailSize = 3 * xThumbnail * yThumbnail;
            currentOffset += thumbnailSize;
            [fileHandle seekToFileOffset:currentOffset];
        } else if (0xe3 == markerValue) {
            markerFound = YES;
            break;
        } else if (0xdb == markerValue) {
            dqtFound = YES;
            break;
        } else {
            NSData *lengthData = [fileHandle readDataOfLength:2];
            currentOffset += 2;
            NSInteger length = (unsigned short)*(unsigned short *)[lengthData bytes];
            length = NSSwapBigShortToHost(length);
            length -= 2;
            currentOffset += length;
            [fileHandle seekToFileOffset:currentOffset];
        }
    }
```

This gives you the offset to the APP3 marker, incase you need to add your own app3 marker you can use a similar approach.